# how to find and replace nth row and nth column value in unix

Tags: unix, replace, row, col

(Unix):I have a file containing 10 lines, my requirement is to find 8th line and replace 3rd column with a value "**NEW**". (file needs to be updated, later when I will view the file it should have new value)

Comment: Can you upload the contents of your file and also the source code you used to achieve this. This way we can help you better.

Comment: did you tried something ?

Comment: awk '$1 ~ /hi$/ {$3 = "me"}1' testfile4      I tried this, but it print only, it wont update in file

Comment: file contains "this is test file"  only one line, and if I want to replace "New" in place of "test", but using column and row number.

Comment: @vishal: please see my answer.

Comment: Thank you, Suresh. It is working. But, can we make it short?   
I am trying to do this, " sed -i '1s/is/vishal/' testfile4 ". Here I place of "is" I want to give the address of that position i.e. column number. Please help, if we can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below sed command.

```
sed -i '2s/^\(\([^ \t]\+[ \t]\)\{2\}\)[^ \t]\+/\1New/g' a.txt
```

In this the first number 2 is for which line you want to substitute.

Then in the regular expression, inside the braces({}), After which column you have to substitute the word. For example, you have to substitute the 3rd column, then you have to give the 2 in that place.